# what would be appropriate to write in the footer of a Joomla template if the template was downloaded for free

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla1.7, joomla-template

Sometimes I get into a situation when I need to deliver a website in a very short period of time and in that case I use to download joomla templates from the internet, modify it as per my requirement and then deliver it.

Now my question is since I am downloading the template free from the internet I assume I don't have the right to write "Developed by My Name/Company Name" in the footer of the website and if my assumption is correct , then what would be appropriate to write in the footer if I also want others to know that I also have some contribution to make the website live.?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the license that the template you use is being distributed under. They are all different and some would allow you to do basically anything you want, like GPL is pretty flexible. While other licenses don't allow any modification to the code, others don't allow any distribution without consent, all kinds of stuff.

You need to look at the license before you do anything, that will spell out what you can and can't do.

Answer (score 0):

Write whatever is appropriate.
If you developed it and tweaked the template considerably - put your info there (if the client is okay with that).  Publicity is always good.

The free templates are often part of the GPL so you can do with them as you please.  Although you have to be careful because some of those 'free' templates end up loading additional things which quietly publicize their own business.  Read through [THIS THREAD](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2703095) to get an idea of what I'm talking about and which template sites do that.